What's the source of the so-called Chinese proverb, "it is only when mosquito land on your balls..."
Recently a tweet from @Cultination1 on X went viral on the Chinese internet. In the tweet, the following quote is labelled as "Chinese proverb":

« C'est en voyant un moustique se poser sur ses testicules qu'on réalise qu'on ne peut pas régler tous les problèmes par la violence.. »
https://x.com/Cultination1/status/1774798500435255797

On the Internet, similar quotes have been attributed to Confucius, to Laozi. On a blog, it is said that in Mali there is a similar saying. The oldest source I can find about it seems to be Bernard Werber's L'Encyclopédie du savoir relatif et absolu (1993)
(https://booknode.com/troisieme_humanite_tome_3_la_voix_de_la_terre_01332665/extraits), where it is attributed with a Chinese origin. Is this book really the origin of this quote? Or is there any older source of it?
